# Why can data type not be serialized although it is member of the show class?

Tags: haskell

```
data Mine = Firstname String
          | Lastname String
          deriving (Show, Serialize)
```

This does not compile and gives the error

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Serialize'
```

Why is this not seen as member of the Serialize class although it is member of the Show class. I thought that all members of the Show class should serialize without problems?

Comment: I don't think you can derive `Serialize` like that...

Comment: Also note that while the statement that every type with a sensible `Show` instance should also admit a sensible `Serialize` instance is true, it is still not automatic. The `Serialize` class is about efficient binary encodings of values, whereas `Show` is about human-readable textual representations. Both are quite different things, and just using a binary encoding of the `Show` output would be very inefficient in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error is saying that the `Serialize` typeclass is not in scope.  You need to import the package that defines the typeclass in order to use it.  You probably want:

```
import Data.Serialize
```

from the [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/latest/doc/html/Data-Serialize.html#t%3aSerialize) package.

Comment: Thanks, had imported cereal in the wrong module and not re-exproted it. However, I now see that "Serialize is not a derivable class."

Comment: I'm not familiar with how it works but check out the [cereal-derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-derive) package.

Comment: @AndrewMyers: Packages to "derive" type classes typically either use TH to write instances for you, or use GHC's generics and provide an `instance (Generic a) => Foo a where` default instance or generic implementations you can use to write an instance. `cereal-derive` seems to be the latter, but it looks like `cereal` supports something similar automatically, as in mhwombat's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to automatically derive Serialize for your class, you can do it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Serialize (Serialize)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Mine = Firstname String
          | Lastname String
          deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Serialize Mine
```